# Compact small electricity generator using induction coil

Tags: motor, electromagnetism, generator, brushless-dc-motor, induction-motor

Traditional brushless motors use wound induction coils surrounded by permanent magnets. Would it be possible to create a less efficient version generator by rearranging the orientation of the coils to make it more compact?

The top view is shown below - the grey bars are two (preferably one) neodymium magnets. The coils would be quite thin - around 1-2mm thick.

And if so, how could I calculate how much power could be generated? (from the size of the magnets?). How would I size the coil windings? Ideally, it would generate <100mA

[image]

[image]

Comment: [pancake+motor](https://www.google.ie/search?q=pancake+motor).

Comment: Scale this one down. http://scoraigwind.co.uk/a-wind-turbine-recipe-book/ or http://www.scoraigwind.com/pmgbooklet/itpmg.pdf or http://www.scoraigwind.com/pirate%20oldies/Hugh%20Piggott%20Axial-flow%20PMG%20wind%20turbine%20May%202003.pdf from http://www.scoraigwind.com/download/index.htm

Answer (score 0):

If you watch Hippolyte Pixii's generator, you see easily that it's possible to get what you asked.

https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/56/Wechselstromerzeuger.jpg

The linked image has a dc version of Pixii's generator - the brushes can be left out if you can accept AC output. More pole pairs and modern magnets - it surely will be acceptably effective even as flat.

You really should consider to have

- as many magnets as coils
- proper magnetic circuit

Without them it's radically less effective.

Learn more from general electric machine theory & design texbooks.